# Simplifying return from multiple nested blocks in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

The code in question is as:

```
fun get(context: Context, s: String): MyObjectDb? {
    return context.database.use {
        return@use select(MyObjectDb.TABLE_NAME, *MyObjectDb.PROJECTION)
                    .whereArgs("${MyObjectDb.COLUMN_S} = {s}", "s" to s)
                        .exec {
                            return@exec getOne(MyObjectDb::fromCursor)
                        }
    }
}
```

When I check this for code style (sonar with Kotlin plugin that uses detekt) I get a warning that I should "Restrict the number of return statements in methods."

Is there a way to only return in return@exec or to write the code in more Kotlinized way - without so many returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can omit `return` when a lambda only contain a single expression. Since your function also only contains a single expression, you can write the function body after a `=` to omit the return here too. You can therefore shorten your code to this:

```
fun get(context: Context, s: String): MyObjectDb? = context.database.use {
    select(MyObjectDb.TABLE_NAME, *MyObjectDb.PROJECTION)
        .whereArgs("${MyObjectDb.COLUMN_S} = {s}", "s" to s)
        .exec { getOne(MyObjectDb::fromCursor) }
}
```